Vite setup with multiple input
I struggling with vite setting.　I want to output the typescript's files under entry_point to the directory under dist as shown in the diagram below.
┣━　src/　━　entry_point　━━ pageA.ts
┃　　　　　　　　　　　　┃　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　┗  pageB.ts
┃　　　　　　　　　　　　┃
┃　　　　　　　　　　　　┗ modules ━━━┯ a.ts
┃                　　　　　　┣ b.ts
┃                   ┗ c.ts
┗━ dist ┯ pageA.js
        ┣ pageB.js
        ┗ b-[hash].js // I don't want to output this.

/* pageA.ts */
import { a } from '../modules/a';
import { b } from '../modules/b';

a(b);

/* pageB.ts */
import { a } from '../modules/a';
import { c } from '../modules/b';

a(c);

However, a common file like b-[hash].js is additionally output.
I want to output a single output associated with each input.
The configuration file for vite is as follows.
export default defineConfig({
  base: './',
  build: {
    outDir: './dist/',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: Object.fromEntries(
        [
          ...globSync('src/entry_point/**/*.ts').map(file => [
            path.relative(
              'src/entry_point',
              file.slice(0, file.length - path.extname(file).length),
            ),
            fileURLToPath(new URL(file, import.meta.url)),
          ]),
        ]
      ),
      output: {
        entryFileNames: data => {
          return '[name].js';
        },
      },
    },
  }
});

I want to output a single output associated with each input. The configuration file for vite is as follows.

Does this answer your question? How can I customize the output filename when multiple inputs in rollup.js?
